# Implications of updating Amazon RDS SSL/TLS certificates by March 5, 2020 in Codeignier application & AWS Lambda functions

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, ssl, amazon-rds

Recently I got a message/notification from Amazon

> Update your Amazon RDS SSL/TLS certificates before March 5, 2020
>
> To avoid interruption of your applications using RDS and Aurora databases, update the Certificate Authority (CA) certificates for these databases before March 5, 2020. We strongly recommend making your updates before February 5, 2020, to leave time for deployments, testing, and validation. New databases created after January 14, 2020, will default to using the new CA certificates. Make sure that you update your client applications with the new certificates first. Find the new CA certificates and info: RDS Aurora

We have few DB instances in RDS & we also have Codeigniter applications which are connecting through RDS DB instances.

So my question is if I update SSL/TLS Certificates in RDS, then do I have to use those DB config variables to connect DB instances in RDS ?

```
$db['default']['ssl_set'] = true;   
$db['default']['ssl_key'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_cert'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_ca'] = realpath('./application/third_party/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem');
$db['default']['ssl_capath'] = NULL;
$db['default']['ssl_cipher'] = NULL
```

Does this also applies (use pem file in python to connect) in AWS Lambda functions ? since we have few functions in python which are connects to same RDS DB instances

Comment: If the path/fileName values are the same you should be good to go.